# nodejs adding double quotes to command arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, child-process, spawn

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -metadata title="Test 123" -c copy temp.mkv
```

ffmpeg sees `""Test 123""`. It happens with spawn() and execFile()

If I run the same command in the windows shell ffmpeg sees it correctly as `"Test 123"`

So what's up with nodejs?

Here's the nodejs code:

```
var process = spawn('ffmpeg', [
  '-i',
  inFile,
  '-metadata',
  'title="Test 123"',     
  '-c',
  'copy',
  outFile
]);
```

Comment: You need to show us the Node.js code that doesn't work, not the shell command that does work.

Comment: ok I posted the code, I'm using child_process module btw

Comment: Why don't you use `exec`, or `execSync`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Child Process Issue with Args - Quotes Issue?, FFMPEG issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310468/node-js-child-process-issue-with-args-quotes-issue-ffmpeg-issue)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to switch to `"title='Test 123'"` since double quotes have precedence over single quotes. Your `stdin` should then just parse it right to `title="Test 123"`.